# MySQL: Obtener pedidos completos con un subconjunto de productos

Tags: mysql, base-de-datos, mysqli, iphone

El problema que tenemos es el siguiente. Tenemos una base de datos shop_orders con pedidos realizados por clientes:

```
id | user_id
1  | 1
```

Por otro lado tenemos la tabla shop_order_products, que contiene los productos que contiene cada pedido, donde el campo order_id relaciona ambas tablas:

```
id | order_id | qty | product_id | product_name | product_price |
1  | 1        |  2  | 23         | samsung S5   | 40.5
2  | 1        |  1  | 12         | iPhone 6S    | 80
```

Sólo por clarificar, en este ejemplo el pedido 1 cuenta con 2 unidades de Samsung y 1 unidad de iPhone.

Nosotros somos capaces de saber, mediante la tabla shop_order_products, cuáles son los productos más vendidos de nuestra tienda online, mediante la llamada:

```
 SELECT *, COUNT(*) as sales FROM shop_order_products GROUP BY order_id ORDER BY sales DESC
```

Necesitamos, dado un subconjunto de productos, saber cuántos pedidos COMPLETOS podríamos sacar. Es decir, si nosotros tuvieramos que los productos que más vendemos son el iPhone 6S y el Samsung Galaxy S5, cuántos pedidos completos sacaríamos con esos dos productos. Si un pedido contiene ambos productos pero también otros, no se tendría en cuenta para nuestro cálculo.

Comment: ¿Queréis hacer como una previsión de ventas? No entiendo muy bien lo que se pide con _si nosotros tuvieramos que los productos que más vendemos son el iPhone 6S y el Samsung Galaxy S5, cuántos pedidos completos sacaríamos con esos dos productos._

Comment: No. Nosotros ahora mismo trabajamos mediante Dropshipping: es decir, cuando nos llega un pedido se lo pasamos a nuestro proveedor para que se lo envíe al cliente. Queremos empezar a montar nuestro almacén en breve, y por eso queremos saber cuántas referencias necesitaremos para cubrir buena parte de los envíos nosotros mismos.

Answer (score 1):

No se si es exactamente lo que buscáis, pero a ver si os puedo ayudar:

```
SELECT 
    o.*, COUNT(o.id)
FROM
    shop_orders o
    LEFT JOIN shop_order_products op ON op.order_id = o.id
    LEFT JOIN
        (SELECT 
            p.id
        FROM
            product p where p.id = 1 or p.id = 2) 
        AS custom_product ON op.product_id = custom_product.id
GROUP BY o.id
HAVING COUNT(custom_product.id) = 2;
```

Te comento que en el segundo `LEFT JOIN` se deben añadir todos los productos que quieres filtrar (se busca por 2 productos, el 1 y el 2 ) y también configurar el `HAVING COUNT` con el número de productos que tiene que tener el pedido (2 productos en este caso)

Espero que sea de ayuda.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entiendo quieres una consulta que te traiga el número de (por ejemplo) iphones 6, pero solo las ordenes que han comprado única y exclusivamente un iphone 6, es decir que si compraron un samnsung como en la orden 1, está no se tome en cuenta en la suma?

```
SELECT COUNT(*),
FROM shop_order_products 
WHERE order_id IN 
  (SELECT order_id 
   FROM shop_order_products 
   GROUP BY order_id 
   HAVING (COUNT = 1)
  )
GROUP BY order_id;
```